# Solve for $x$ with exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to solve an equation to find a value of $x$ like this:

$(1.08107)^{98/252}=(1.08804+x)^{23/252}(1.08804+2x)^{37/252}(1.08804+3x)^{38/252}$

That is pretty straightforward using Excel Solver, but I am not quite grasping how to do it by hand.

The result is $-0.00323$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: There may be a solution more simply rendered than MS Excel's -0.00323.

Comment: What do you mean Oscar? Thanks for the reply

Comment: A whole number maybe?

Comment: I am sorry. 1.08 is rounded, I wanted to make the post clearer because I am interested in the resolution and not the result itself. I'll edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: Moo, I edited the question before to put the decimals because I didn't realize that would be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a [*root finding algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms), like Newton's Method.

Our function is given by

$$f(x) =  1.03078 -(x+1.08804)^{23/252} (2 x+1.08804)^{37/252} (3 x+1.08804)^{19/126}$$

The Newton iteration is given by

$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n - \dfrac{
  1.03078 -(x+1.08804)^{23/252} (2 x+1.08804)^{37/252} (3 x+1.08804)^{19/126} }{\left(-\dfrac{23 (2 x+1.08804)^{37/252} (3 x+1.08804)^{19/126}}{252 (x+1.08804)^{229/252}}-\dfrac{37 (x+1.08804)^{23/252} (3 x+1.08804)^{19/126}}{126 (2 x+1.08804)^{215/252}}-\dfrac{19 (x+1.08804)^{23/252} (2 x+1.08804)^{37/252}}{42 (3 x+1.08804)^{107/126}}\right)}$

Starting at $x_0 = 1$, we arrive at

$$x \approx -0.003235904357553754$$

Comment: Thanks Moo. I put that into Python and the answer matches my work in Excel.

Comment: Excellent to hear that! Great job.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to ignore the $252$, converting the equation to

$$(1.08107)^{98}=(1.08804+x)^{23}(1.08804+2x)^{37}(1.08804+3x)^{38}$$

(that is, raise both sides to the $252$th power). Now, since $98=23+37+38$, we can move the left hand side to the right, giving

$$1=\left(1.08804+x\over1.08107\right)^{23}\left(1.08804+2x\over1.08107\right)^{37}\left(1.08804+3x\over1.08107\right)^{38}$$

Noting $1.08804=1.08107+0.00697$ and taking logs, we have

$$\begin{align}
0&=23\ln\left(1+{x+0.00697\over1.08107}\right)+37\ln\left(1+{2x+0.00697\over1.08107}\right)+38\ln\left(1+{2x+0.00697\over1.08107}\right)\\
&\approx23\cdot{x+0.00697\over1.08107}+37\cdot{2x+0.00697\over1.08107}+38\cdot{3x+0.00697\over1.08107}\\
&={(23+74+114)x+98\cdot0.00697\over1.08107}\\
&={211x+0.68306\over1.08107}\\
&\implies x\approx-0.68306/211=0.00323725\ldots
\end{align}$$

This gets us in the ballpark of the asserted result. In fact, the true answer is somewhere between $0-.00323$ and $-0.003237$: The right hand side of the first equation is larger than $(1.081076)^{98}$ for $x=-0.00323$ and smaller for $x=-0.003237$.

The key here is the approximation $\ln(1+u)\approx u$ if $|u|$ is small, which turns out to be the case. One could get a better approximation using $\ln(1+u)\approx u-{1\over2}u^2$, but that would lead to a messy quadratic equation to solve for $x$.

Comment: Nice approach + 1